# How to draw contours for rough data set without triangulation, matching pcolormesh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, contour

I have a pretty rough data set I am using to draw a phase diagram with matplotlib's [pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html).
`x,y` are 2D numpy arrays and represent a uniform grid at the moment. `z` contains integers ranging from `1`-`9`, each number matching a phase. The option `shading='nearest'` centers the color chosen according to `z` at `(x,y)`. My colormap is segmented matching the possible `z` values.

```
vmin, vmax = 1, 9
colors = ['blue', 'orange', 'black', 'gray', 'cyan', 'lime', 'yellow', 'green', 'red']
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
axes[0].pcolormesh(x, y, z, shading = 'nearest', vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax, cmap = cmap)
```

With this I get the upper subplot which is acceptable for me.
[image]

However, some of the phases have common properties which is why I would like to add contours. For example, I would like to draw a contour that separates the colored and the black/gray parts. I have two problems here:

1. It would be great if I could use [contour](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) but I cannot manage to do so, see the second subplot drawn with [contourf](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html), without it triangulating(?) my data. This would not be a problem if I had a lot more data points but it is unlikely that I will increase the resolution by much. Even if I could live with triangulation: No yellow area should be drawn. But since z jumps from `z=8`(green) to `z = 6`(lime) contour inserts an intermediate yellow area.
2. Depending on how we solve this problem: I would really like to be able to draw contours both for connected and disconnected areas.

An idea I have is defining a new phase that covers lime, green and cyan and then outline that area. The data manipulation for this is simple, however, I do not know how to proceed with matplotlib after that. Besides, I do not know how one would identify connected and disconnected cells.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come of with the following setup that I am almost satisfied with:

The key is the so-called [**alpha shape**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape). It is in essence a triangulation, roughly speaking for determining the bounding polygon of a set of points. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/) is the corresponding python module. It was very simple to implement. I had no prior experience with shapely. In addition, I had to dig a bit into matplotlib's [pcolor](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.1/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L5628-L5870) source code. In the end I came up with the following script, main code is at the bottom.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy.ma as ma
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import alphashape

#various parameters
nrows, ncols = 1, 1

# create segmented colormap with 9 colors (I will need 9 colors in my actual application)
colors = ['blue', 'orange', 'black', 'gray', 'cyan', 'lime', 'yellow', 'green', 'red']
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
# set vmin and vmax from 1 to 9
vmin = 1
vmax = 9
# name of the saved imagefile
savename = 'plot_alpha_shape'

# alpha value for the alpha shape, dont confuse it with the opacity from the
# standard mpl kwargs
alpha = 0.5
# grid discretization
dx = 2.0
dy = 1
# create 2d rectangular mesh
x, y = np.meshgrid(dx*np.arange(3), dy*np.arange(4))
# create homogeneous demo data
z = np.ones_like(x)*2
# change some values to make z heterogeneous
z[0] = np.ones(3)
z[1,-1] = 1
# define mask for the contour
mask = z>1
z_masked = ma.masked_array(z, mask = mask)

pcolor_kwargs = dict(shading = 'nearest', vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax, cmap = cmap)
contour_kwargs = dict(fc = 'none', ec = 'k', linewidth = 3)

def get_quadrilateral_vertices(x,y):
  X = interp_grid(x)
  Y = interp_grid(y)
  X = interp_grid(X.T).T
  Y = interp_grid(Y.T).T
  return X, Y

def interp_grid(X):
  dX = np.diff(X, axis=1)/2.
  X = np.hstack((X[:, [0]] - dX[:, [0]],
                  X[:, :-1] + dX,
                  X[:, [-1]] + dX[:, [-1]]))
  return X


def get_xymask(x,y):
  # merge x and y masks in case they are different
  mask = ma.getmaskarray(x) + ma.getmaskarray(y)
  # map mask to the cells in order to merge it with z mask
  xymask = (mask[0:-1, 0:-1] + mask[1:, 1:] +
            mask[0:-1, 1:] + mask[1:, 0:-1])
  return xymask

def execute_masking(x,y,z):
  # get dimensions
  Ny, Nx = x.shape
  xymask = get_xymask(x,y)
  # merge all masks
  # don't plot if C or any of the surrounding vertices are masked.
  mask = ma.getmaskarray(z) + xymask

  unmask = ~mask
  X1 = ma.filled(x[:-1, :-1])[unmask]
  Y1 = ma.filled(y[:-1, :-1])[unmask]
  X2 = ma.filled(x[1:, :-1])[unmask]
  Y2 = ma.filled(y[1:, :-1])[unmask]
  X3 = ma.filled(x[1:, 1:])[unmask]
  Y3 = ma.filled(y[1:, 1:])[unmask]
  X4 = ma.filled(x[:-1, 1:])[unmask]
  Y4 = ma.filled(y[:-1, 1:])[unmask]
  # npoly = len(X1)

  xy = np.stack([X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4], axis=-1)
  # one vertex is duplicate in the original code
  # xy = np.stack([X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4, X1, Y1], axis=-1)
  # transform to array of xy pairs
  verts = xy.reshape((-1, 2))
  z = ma.filled(z[:Ny - 1, :Nx - 1])[unmask]
  return verts, z

def get_masked_data(x,y,z):
  X, Y = get_quadrilateral_vertices(x,y)
  # convert to MA, if necessary.
  z = ma.asarray(z)
  X = ma.asarray(X)
  Y = ma.asarray(Y)
  return execute_masking(X,Y,z)

def plot_vertices(ax, verts):
  verts = verts.T
  ax.plot(*verts, linestyle = '', marker = 'x', color = 'r', ms = 10)


# main code
# x,y,z are cellcentered data
# use get_masked_data and its inner functions to get the vertices of the
# cells used in pcolor
# we are not using zdummy here
verts, zdummy = get_masked_data(x,y,z_masked)
# map vertices to a list of (x,y) tuples, each representing one vertex
contour_data = list(zip(verts[:,0], verts[:,1]))
# create an alpha shape from the vertices
contour_alphashape = alphashape.alphashape(verts, alpha)

# create figure with one subplot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15/2.54,nrows*4/2.54), constrained_layout=True)
gs = GridSpec(nrows, ncols, figure=fig)
axes = [fig.add_subplot(gs[j,i]) for j in range(nrows) for i in range(ncols)]

# plot vertices
plot_vertices(axes[0], verts)
# plot pcolor
pmesh1 = axes[0].pcolor(x,y,z, **pcolor_kwargs)
# plot the contour using alphashape
contour = PolygonPatch(contour_alphashape,**contour_kwargs)
axes[0].add_patch(contour)


# save the plot
plt.savefig(savename + '.png')
```

Almost all of the defined functions are taken from matplotlib's [pcolor](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.1/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L5628-L5870) and [_pcolorargs](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/710fce3df95e22701bd68bf6af2c8adbc9d67a79/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L5503).

The alpha shape will become more detailed the larger you choose alpha. For very small alpha you will get a convex hull. I am attaching the result of the script.
[image]

As you can see, the contour does not exactly match the blue area. If alpha becomes too large, alpha shape will not return a proper polygon if I understood it correctly which is why I cannot make the contour align even tighter. I think it has something to do with the regular spacing of my data, too.